# What algorithm to count user click/read/turnover for a period of time?

Tags: algorithms, statistics

We tried to develop a kinda-real-time statistics module to measure how hot/trend a content is. We know it is hard to achieve high end stuff like youtube/FB/twitter, our goal is simpler :

- Count click/read/like/etc.. during the last hour/day/week/etc..
- Calculate some basic indexes such as likeCount/clickCount, readCount/turnOverCount, etc...
- Use the data  in step 2 above for report or as input of other

We used mysql to log every user action on a content. After 1 month, the table got 10 billions rows when our website had around 2000 content and 1 million unique visitor a day. After 2 months, the query became unbearable slow :

```
Select count(*) from log_table where content_id = xxx and timestamp > (now - yyy)
```

Of course we have index on content_id  and timestamp and the database size got very big.

I guess our solution is quite child-ish.. Is there a better algorithm to solve this? (How do Youtube/Twitter do to solve this  in general) ?

P/S : I recently read about HyperLogLog, somehow understand it, can it help in this case ?

Comment: Does the brute force approach of putting it into a SQL database and querying it work? If so, start with that.

Comment: @PhilipKendall : i don't think so, it works but not sustainable after 2 months...